# Существуют ли сейчас nntp сервера?

Tags: python-3.x

Наткнулся в книге Марка Лутца на код:

```
"""
fetch and print usenet newsgroup posting from comp.lang.python via the
nntplib module, which really runs on top of sockets; nntplib also supports
posting new messages, etc.; note: posts not deleted after they are read;
"""

listonly = False
showhdrs = ['From', 'Subject', 'Date', 'Newsgroups', 'Lines']
try:
    import sys
    servername, groupname, showcount = sys.argv[1:]
    showcount  = int(showcount)
except:
    servername = 'ddt.demos.su'       # assign this to your server
    groupname  = 'fido7.aaa.support'          # cmd line args or defaults
    showcount  = 10                          # show last showcount posts

# connect to nntp server
print('Connecting to', servername, 'for', groupname)
from nntplib import NNTP
connection = NNTP(servername)
(reply, count, first, last, name) = connection.group(groupname)
print('%s has %s articles: %s-%s' % (name, count, first, last))

# get request headers only
fetchfrom = str(int(last) - (showcount-1))
(reply, subjects) = connection.xhdr('subject', (fetchfrom + '-' + last))

# show headers, get message hdr+body
for (id, subj) in subjects:                  # [-showcount:] if fetch all hdrs
    print('Article %s [%s]' % (id, subj))
    if not listonly and input('=> Display?') in ['y', 'Y']:
        reply, num, tid, list = connection.head(id)
        for line in list:
            for prefix in showhdrs:
                if line[:len(prefix)] == prefix:
                    print(line[:80])
                    break
        if input('=> Show body?') in ['y', 'Y']:
            reply, num, tid, list = connection.body(id)
            for line in list:
                print(line[:80])
    print()
print(connection.quit())
```

Хотелось бы увидеть его в действии, но нормальных nntp серверов не нашел.

Comment: http://gmane.org/

Answer (score 0):

Тут например есть: 
https://help.easynews.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2190531-nntp-server-addresses
Полагаю ещё должны быть, также на английском. В россии мне кажется врятле.